# Does the requiresActiveX=true meta tag actually work?

Tags: html, microsoft-metro, meta-tags, internet-explorer-10

I've read a bunch of blog posts, [like this one](http://caioproiete.net/en/request-user-to-switch-to-desktop-version-of-internet-explorer-on-a-website/), and also some other questions here on SO, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973051/redirect-user-to-desktop-browser-in-windows-8).

These all say that if you want to popup a message advising the visitor that the Desktop mode of IE 10 is required to view the site, then 'all you have to do' is add this meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="requiresActiveX=true" />
```

Or you can set an HTTP header instead:

```
<add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="requiresActiveX=true" />
```

I've tried both of these techniques and neither of them seem to work! The Modern UI version of IE just does nothing at all. No popup, no message, nothing.

I'm running my site locally at the moment through IIS 8. I've added the URL to my trusted sites list. If I use another browser, like Chrome, I can see that the response header is definitely being set. The page runs in IE10 Modern, it just doesn't tell me to switch to Desktop mode...

I've tried strategically positioning the `<meta` tag in different places in the `<head` etc but this has not helped either

Can anyone offer any advice? Even mentioning a site that implements it would help...

## Edit

I've tried adding this to a 'live' web page [on my own site](http://www.danwellman.co.uk/steampad/steampad.html) and still I am not prompted to switch to desktop when using IE10 Modern...

Comment: I receive the notification to switch to desktop on the link you posted in the Edit. Perhaps there is an issue with your install somehow?

Comment: Hmm, yes it is intermittently working for me now as well...

Comment: I am having the same issue, but if I refresh the page it will then work and I get the message at the bottom to switch to desktop. It only seems to fail on the initial load. This is the case for both the meta tag and setting in the header through IIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure this will address it for you but it did for me. I had to combine multiple Compat tags into a single entry. Lke this:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7, requiresActiveX=true"/>`