# IE 10 Metro/Modern Browser to IE 10 Desktop Browser

Tags: internet-explorer, iis, microsoft-metro

Have a website that requires plug-ins.

If user is running Win 8 IE 10 Metro/Modern browser want it to message popup at bottom of page that they need to use desktop IE 10.

Recommended solution is:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="requiresActiveX=true" />
```

or an entry in the header via IIS:

```
X-UA-Compatible: requiresActiveX=true
```

I have tried both of these with the same results. I get nothing on the page until after I refresh the page and then it works perfectly.

Anybody know why it is only working after a refresh?

Comment: Have you tried with setting both i.e. meta tag as well as header. Also see this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973051/redirect-user-to-desktop-browser-in-windows-8 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj193557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Yes, all of that was tried. The problem is none of that works until after I refresh the page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Silverlight app disappears on page refresh in IE10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13492045/silverlight-app-disappears-on-page-refresh-in-ie10)